# Nexus 5 Suddenly starts playing music

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, 5.1-lollipop

I have a google nexus 5 which is a year old. I had no issues with it until recently, from around 3 days ago.

Music started playing suddenly from nowhere. It's not from the music player, and it doesn't show any notification, either. I can't even stop the music as I couldn't find out from where it is started playing. I had to turn off my phone to get it to stop.

What can I do to stop this from happening?

Comment: I have the same issue with Cyanogen mod OnePlus

Comment: @Slartibartfast with Cyanogen mod its probably a Gesture... Go to Settings >> Gestures >> uncheck Music.

Comment: Did that, the particular song it plays (Smells like teen spirit by Nirvana -lol!) doesnot exist ANYWHERE in my system. I've scanned the entire device for the song and uninstalled all external music apps. I have to open google play music app and play something else for it to stop.